# Although items are being saved in core data, not able to view them until a relaunch

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, parent-child

Here is an example where `FetchedResultsController` is used in the `ViewController`, and the saves from another `ViewController` are not being passed across to it.

1. MainVC.swift

   ```
   lazy var coreDataManager = CoreDataManager()

   // Initialize fetched request
   private var fetchRecordRequestController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   // Initialize managedObjectContext
   let mainManagedObjectContext = coreDataManager.managedObjectContext

   // Create Fetch Request
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Record")

   // Configure Fetch Request
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]

   // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
   fetchRecordRequestController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: mainManagedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

   // Configure Fetched Results Controller
   fetchRecordRequestController.delegate = self

   // Fetch data from object
   do {
       try fetchRecordRequestController.performFetch()
   } catch let fetchError as NSError {
       print("(RootViewController)fetchError: \(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
   }

   // Add observer in NSNotificationCenter for NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange), name: NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification, object: mainManagedObjectContext)

   override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
   }

   // MARK: - NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Methods

   func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
       tableView.beginUpdates()
   }

   // Delete corresponding row in tableView
   func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
   switch type {
   case .Insert:
       tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
   case .Delete:
       tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
   case .Update:
       tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
   case .Move:
       tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
       tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
   }
   }

   func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
   tableView.endUpdates()
   }

   func managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

   let mainManagedObjectContext = coreDataManager.managedObjectContext
   guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }

   if let inserts = userInfo[NSInsertedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> where inserts.count > 0 {
       print("--- INSERTS ---")
       print(inserts)
       print("+++++++++++++++")
       do {
           try mainManagedObjectContext.save()
       } catch let saveError as NSError {
           print("(RootViewController)saveError: \(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
       }
   }

   if let updates = userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> where updates.count > 0 {
       print("--- UPDATES ---")
       for update in updates {
           print(update.changedValues())
       }
       print("+++++++++++++++")
   }

   if let deletes = userInfo[NSDeletedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> where deletes.count > 0 {
       print("--- DELETES ---")
       print(deletes)
       print("+++++++++++++++")
   }
   }
   ```
2. AddRecordVC.swift

   ```
   // Method to save the extracted values to CoreData Objects
   private func saveValues() {
   // Initializing
   let mainManagedObjectContext = coreDataManager.managedObjectContext
   // Initialize entity description
   let RecordDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Record",inManagedObjectContext:mainManagedObjectContext)
   let record = Record(entity: RecordDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: mainManagedObjectContext)
   // Set object values from temporary variables
   record.date = dateTemp!
   record.tareWeight = tareWeightTemp
   record.grossWeight = grossWeightTemp
   record.nettWeight = nettWeightTemp
   record.numberOfBags = numberOfBagsTemp
   record.weightOfBags = weightOfBagsTemp
   record.rivaju = rivajuTemp
   record.putti = puttiTemp
   record.rateOfPaddy = rateOfPaddyTemp
   record.amount = amountTemp
   // Save the object
   do {
       if mainManagedObjectContext.hasChanges {
           try mainManagedObjectContext.save()
       }
   } catch let saveError as NSError {
       print("(AddRecordViewController)saveError: \(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
   }
   }
   ```

Once, AddRuleVC segues back to RootVC, the view isn't refreshed. **But after the app is quit and relaunched, it does show the data.** A separate class is used for CoreDataStack, which is as below.

3. CoreDataManager.swift

   ```
   class CoreDataManager: NSObject {

   // MARK: - Core Data Stack

   lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
   let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("App Name", withExtension: "momd")!
   return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
   }()

   lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
   // Create the coordinator and store
   let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
   let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
   var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
   do {
       try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
   } catch {
       // Report any error we got.
       var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
       dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
       dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

       dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
       let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
       NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
       abort()
   }

   return coordinator
   }()

   lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
   let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
   var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
   managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
   managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
   return managedObjectContext
   }()
   ```

   // MARK: - Helper Methods

   ```
   func saveContext () {
   if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
       do {
           try managedObjectContext.save()
       } catch {
           let nserror = error as NSError
           NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
           abort()
       }
   }
   }

   lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
   let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
   return urls[urls.count-1]
   }()
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you implemented the fetched results controller delegate methods?

Comment: I've had this problem before. My recommendation is to create a new managed object context every time you set up your fetchedRecordRequestController.

Comment: @jrturton, Yes. I have. The results appear after I force-quit the app and relaunch.

Comment: @MikeTaverne, So, should I setup the `fetchRecordRequestController` in `viewDidAppear`, rather than `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: Can you include them in your question, then? What you're describing happens when the fetched results controller's delegate methods are not implemented, not implemented correctly, or not connected. If you add breakpoints in them, do they get hit? If you do the adds on the same context, as a test, does it work?

Comment: @jrturton, I have only one. `// Reload table when CoreData changes
    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }`

Comment: @jrturton. Nope, they don't. But, I presume, when the parent context is modified, the changes will be picked by the method. I've mentioned above?

Comment: It should, yes. Basically there's nothing wrong with the code in your question, which means the problem is somewhere else so all we can do is guess. If the methods aren't getting hit, then the delegate isn't set right. Are you disconnecting it? Are you re-creating the FRC somewhere?

Comment: Is this okay? 'self.fetchRecordRequestController.delegate = self` I have it while setting up my FRC. I don't think I am explicitly disconnecting it anywhere. Nope, FRC is created only once in my RootVC, and that's it. Any  chance that my AddRuleVC delegates should be checked?

Comment: @jrturton, I've added more info to the question. Sorry for missing this out earlier. Would you please, suggest?

Comment: Your fetched results controller delegate is only taking action when rows are deleted. In comments you said you were reloading the table, but in the question you're not doing that.

Comment: @jrturton, I've added as you've suggested. But, there is still no difference. `Delete` method gets called, when I swipe to delete. But, while there is a change in child/parent context, `Insert` is never called. The changes are happening, but they seem to be not getting picked up.

Comment: A few things,  
1. Can you implement other additions to fetched results controller delegate as well, namely,  .Move, .Refresh rows.
2. If you are using delete/insert/refresh rows at index paths methods then you should write beginUpdates(controllerWillChangeContent) and endUpdates(controllerDidChangeContent).

Comment: @jarora, well, I don't actually need .Move or .Refresh. Should I try implementing them, still? I don't need .Move, as I sort them while fetching. I'm not exactly sure about the use case of .Refresh, though!

Comment: @jarora, well, I did implement. But, it seems to not shed any light on this mystery. Guess, my `FetchedResultsController`, is not picking up the save notifications performed on `mainManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: @jrturton, I have added more code, which might help you in solving this issue, which is just not making me move, any further!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CoreDataManager` class is generating a new managed object context inside `AddRecordVC` different from the one in `MainVC` so when you save the second context the persistent store will be updated but the changes won't be reflected in the first context unless you merge the changes.

This is not good, you only want one context for the main thread. So what you should do is use dependency injection for the managed object context. Kick off the `CoreDataManager` when your app starts up and then inject the context into the `MainVC`, then when you segue to `AddRecordVC` just pass the same context along there too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your tableview by doing `tableview.reloadData()` asynchronously after saving new item.